# Refresh a image in modal window after replaced without Closing modal

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I try to refresh my image in a modal window after being replaced.
If I repeat my operation without closing the modal window, my `<div>` shows all successive pictures, like here:

[image: Example]

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#img_logo_content').change(function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#img_logo_content')[0].files[0];
        fd.append('file',files);
        fd.append('request',1);

        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response != 0){
                    // Show image preview
                     $('#logo-preview').append("<img src='"+response+"'  height='50' style='display: inline-block;'>");
                }else{
                    alert('file not uploaded');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My modal div

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="img_logo_content" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Votre logo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <!-- Display logo -->
        <div id="logo-preview"></div>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img_logo_content" name="img_logo_content" placeholder="Votre Logo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .append() to .html()

```
$('#logo-preview').html("<img src='"+response+"'  height='50' style='display: inline-block;'>");
```

This should replace the image instead of appending to the end of that element, however, this will replace all html in that element.  Not sure if that is desired or not.

Comment: It's so simple!!! It works fine right now !
I had been searching for 2 hours. I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great, be sure to accept an answer if it solved your problem, happy coding!